# Visual Studio 2019 Historical Debugging not working with Fips

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, fips, historical-debugging

Is Historical Debugging compatible with Fips? Is there any work around?

I'm getting the following error when I try to step back to historical events. "This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms."

Comment: Got some code that can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Amy, I just created the simplest of test apps and way attempted to use historical debugging. The error still occurs; however, the historical debugging worked as intended. Will monitor and update my results.

Comment: Can you confirm that your Group Policy settings have FIPS enabled?

Comment: Yes, this is set at the Group Policy level.